# How to make future day numbers in Monthview gray as though they were in the past

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm making a range of days unselectable in the Month view of the Fullcalendar plugin.  When the user clicks on them, the days don't get selected but I want to get the 'day numbers' on the top right of the cells 'grey' as though they were in the past.  I can't figure out how.  This is what I have so far in the dayRender function:

```
dayRender: function (date, cell) {
  var today = new Date();
  var LeadDt = moment(new Date(tempLead));
  LeadDt = LeadDt.subtract("days", 1);
  var dDate = moment(new Date(date));

  if (LeadDt.diff(dDate) > -1 )
  {
    $(cell).addClass('ui-state-disabled');
    $(cell).closest('td').addClass('unselectable');
    $(cell).push('fc-other-month');// attempt #1 to add fc-other-month class to td - fail
    $(cell).closest("td[data-date='" + moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD") + "']").addClass('fc-other-month'); // attempt #2 to add fc-other-month class to td - fail
  }
},
```

Can anyone let me know how I can accomplish this?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the corresponding data-date attribute and adding the class there:

```
 if (LeadDt.diff(dDate) > -1 )
 {
  cell.addClass('ui-state-disabled');
  cell.closest('td').addClass('unselectable');
  $("td").find("td[data-date='" + moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD") + "']").addClass('fc-other-month');
 }
```